# Forms <select> value not submitted

Tags: jquery, html, forms, prestashop-1.6

I am working on prestashop 1.6 module. There are 3 tabs having 1 form in each tab.
I have combined 3 forms so that they get submitted by clicking any of 3 submit buttons.

The jquery I used:

```
$('.submit_general').bind('click', function () {
    $('#form1 :input').not(':submit').clone().hide().appendTo('#general');
    $('#form2 :input').not(':submit').clone().hide().appendTo('#general');
    $('#form1 select').not(':submit').clone().hide().appendTo('#general');
    $('#form2 select').not(':submit').clone().hide().appendTo('#general');
    console.log($('#form1 select').val());
    console.log($('#form2 select').val());
});
$('.submit_form1').bind('click', function () {
    $('#general :input').not(':submit').clone().hide().appendTo('#form1');
    $('#form2 :input').not(':submit').clone().hide().appendTo('#form1');
    $('#form2 select').not(':submit').clone().hide().appendTo('#form1');
});
$('.submit_form2').bind('click', function () {
    $('#general :input').not(':submit').clone().hide().appendTo('#form2');
    $('#form1 :input').not(':submit').clone().hide().appendTo('#form2');        
    $('#form1 select').not(':submit').clone().hide().appendTo('#form2');        
});
```

select elements in form 2 and form 3 have been added by ajax.

The Problem is when I submit form from "general" tab selected elements in both form1 and form2 don't get submitted. Also when I submit from form1 tab Form1 selected values submitted but not of form2 and vice-versa.

I tested post values by writing in console. It gives the correct result but those are not submitted instead 1st option of both selectors gets posted.

HTML:

```
<form id="form1">
<input type="hidden" name="submitform1" value="1">              
<div class="panel" id="fieldset_form_1">                                        
    <div class="form-wrapper">                        
        <div class="form-group mailigen_form">                
            <div class="col-lg-9">                    
                <div id="list1"><div  style="padding: 7px 0px"><font color="red">No list exists</font></div></div>       
            </div>
        </div>
    </div><!-- /.form-wrapper -->
    <div class="panel-footer">
        <button type="submit" value="1" id="configuration_form_submit_btn_1" name="submitform1" class="submit_form1 btn btn-default pull-right">Save</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

AJAX response added in place of no list text:

```
<select name="form_1" id="form_1">
<option value="1"> Test List 3</option>
<option value="2"> Test List 2</option>
<option value="3"> Test List 1</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Can you paste your form HTML or Just SELECT tag HTML ?

Comment: As an aside, I think there are better ways to solve your problem than cloning & hiding elements like this. Think about whether you can stop the form submitting, gather all of your values, and then send the data,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because when you clone the element and append it to another, it loses it's value. You would need to set an option's selected attribute to true. A better way is to create an input, set its name to the select's value, and its value to the select's value. In the server side, you won't see this, so it doesn't matter if you use input instead of select.

```
$('#form1 select, #form2 select').each(function() {
    $("<input type='hidden' name='"+$(this).attr("name")+"' value='"+$(this).val()+"' />").appendTo('#general');
});
```

Comment: The very important thing is `when you clone the element and append it to another, it loses it's value.` so we have to set it again :) Thanks a lot dear :)